# Securing AWS S3 Objects from direct url access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have an angular application serving as a static hosted site from aws s3 wrapped by a cloudfront distribution. Also, this angular application accesses all images like profile pictures from a different  S3 bucket (which grows overtime). This bucket is also wrapped under a cloudfront distribution.

My intention is to prevent anybody from directly accessing this images using url. Those images should be accessible only from my angular application and not from outside.

I tried adding CORS configuration to my S3 bucket as follows:

```
<CORSRule>
<AllowedOrigin>https://*.XXXX.com</AllowedOrigin>
<AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
<MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
```

Also I added origin whitelist in my cloudfront ditribution for my profile picture bucket. Still I am not able to access my profile pictures wither from browser or my application. It is throwing 403. Can somebody help here please.

Comment: What do you mean by "accessible only from my angular application"? If somebody has the URL, they will be able to access it unless you protect content with Signed URLs.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is to create a Cloud Front Origin Identity and attach it to your distribution. If you do this via the console Cloud Front itself generates the S3 bucket policies that would prevent direct access.(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html#private-content-creating-oai)

PS: CloudFront distribution could take some time to replicate.